# created a new .txt file from other .txt files in c

Tags: c, file

I have 3 .txt files (Q3.txt, Q2.txt and Q1.txt) a number of different lines and each line is an identifier, ex: (7, 25, 75 ...).

This represents the ranking of each race. I would like to create a new "FINAL" file with a start list.

The Q3.txt file therefore contains 10 lines. I would like these 10 lines to be the first 10 of the "FINAL.txt" file.

For the Q2.txt file it has 15 lines, I would like the 10-15 lines to be 10-15 in the "FINAL.txt" file as well.

And finally for the Q1.txt file, I would like the lines 15-20 to be 15-20 in the "FINAL.txt" file as well.

I tried coding but only get 4 lines instead of the expected 20.

Here is the code:

```c
void prepaClassementFinal(void) {

#define NUMBER_OF_STRING 3
#define MAX_STRING_SIZE 14

    char arr[NUMBER_OF_STRING][MAX_STRING_SIZE] = {"./data/Q3.txt", "./data/Q2.txt", "./data/Q1.txt"};

    for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++)
    {
        FILE* file = fopen(arr[i], "r");
        char line[256];
        int j = 0;

        FILE *fichier = fopen("./data/FINAL", "w");
        if (fichier == NULL) {
            perror("fopen() failed !");
            exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
        }

        while (fgets(line, sizeof(line), file)) {
            j++;

            if(i == 0) {
                if(j >= 0 && j < 10) {
                    fprintf(fichier, "%s\n", line);
                }
            }
            if(i == 1){
                if(j >= 10 && j < 15) {
                    fprintf(fichier, "%s\n", line);
                }
            }
            if(i == 2){
                if(j >= 15 && j < 20) {
                    fprintf(fichier, "%s\n", line);
                }
            }
        }
        fclose(fichier);
        fclose(file);
    }
}
```

and here is the result I get:

```
16
10
47
5
55
```

Comment: The [`fopen`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fopen) mode `"w"`truncates the file when opened, all its old contents will be lost.

Comment: Consider writing a function to process an input file.  Also, any reason why you write this in c opposed to `sed` script?

Comment: Also, you should simplify your example, and provide the data or better hard-code it so we can run it for you.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you open and close the file outside the loop:

```
FILE *fichier = fopen("./data/FINAL", "w");
for (int i = 0; i < NUMBER_OF_STRING; i++) {
 ...
}
fclose(fichier);
```

Alternatively, you can do it inside the loop but as @Someprogrammerdude said, then you need to append to the file then:

```
FILE *fichier = fopen("./data/FINAL", "a");
```